# Laravel Scout with Meilisearch filtering not working with >, >=, <, and <= operators

Tags: laravel, laravel-scout, meilisearch

I am trying to implement Meilisearch on my Laravel application.

for some reason I'm not able to filter `decimal` fields (`price`, `mrp` etc..) using `>`, `>=`, `<`, and `<=` operators as explained on [Meilisearch Documentation](https://docs.meilisearch.com/learn/advanced/datatypes.html#numeric:%7E:text=You%20can%20also%20create%20filters.%20The%20%3E%2C%20%3E%3D%2C%20%3C%2C%20and%20%3C%3D%20relational%20operators%20apply%20only%20to%20numerical%20values).

```php
        Product::search($request->search, function ($meilisearch, $query, $options) {
            $options['filter'] = 'price >= 1'; // This is the line that causes the issue.
            return $meilisearch->search($query, $options);
        })->raw();
```

If I do something like above, I get 0 hits, altho there are many records that satisfy that condition (`price >= 1`):

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

---

Also, I want to learn , how can I apply multiple fiters.
Like, in actual scenario. we need to filter the products by min and max price.
I realized that Laravel scout doesn't allow us to use advanced where clauses (`where('price', '>=', $request->min_price)`) like eloquent

I want to do something like this using  **Scout** and **Meilisearch**.

```php
        $query = Product::search($request->search);
        
        if ($request->min_price) {
            $query->where('price', '>=', $request->min_price);
        }
        if ($request->max_price) {
            $query->where('price', '<=', $request->max_price);
        }
```

Answer (score 6):

A hacky way that we are using at the moment is to place the operator into the field:

```php
    $query = Product::search($request->search);
        
    if ($request->min_price) {
        $query->where('price >', $request->min_price);
    }
    if ($request->max_price) {
        $query->where('price <', $request->max_price);
    }
```

That way Scout creates the proper (e.g. `price >= {min_price}`) expression. But beware that this is just **workaround** and does not necessarily work with other search engines supported by Scout.

Please watch Scout's Meilisearch driver for why this works: https://github.com/laravel/scout/blob/9.x/src/Engines/MeiliSearchEngine.php#L163-L188